# (C) strtok with multiple spaces/tabs, checking for null with pointer

Tags: c, string, pointers, tokenize

I am trying to split a string into two tokens using `strtok()` that might have spaces and tabs mixed in the string.

So I made this:

```
struct strstr
{
    char *str, 
         *one, 
         *two;
};

typedef struct strstr *STRSTR;

void split(STRSTR);

int main()
{
    STRSTR str = malloc(sizeof(struct strstr));
    str->str = malloc(256);

    fgets(str->str, 256, stdin);

    split(str);
    printf("%s, %s\n", str->one, str->two);

    free(str->str);
    free(str);

    return 0;
}

void split(STRSTR str)
{
    int i;
    char *temp = str->str;

    while(isspace(*(str->str)))
        str->str++;

    str->one = strtok(str->str, " \t");
    for(i = 0; i < strlen(str->one); i++)
    {
        if(!isspace(str->one[i]))
            str->str++;
    }

    str->str++;

    if(str->str != NULL)
    {
        puts("In null if");
        str->two = strtok(str->str, "");
    }

    str->str = temp;
}
```

So for example if you input `Hello             Earth lingss`, it will print out `Hello, Earth lingss`, which is perfect.

However, if I input `Hello` only, the split function goes inside the `if(str->str != NULL)` statement. How do I stop it from doing that with the code that I have?

EDIT: Also another problem, if someone doesn't mind checking it out. `temp` will only point to the first word in `str->str`. How can I make it point to the whole thing?

Comment: In your loop after the first `strtok` call, you iterate on `str->one` and check for spaces in `str->one`, but you increment `str->str`. Are you supposed to do that? That just looks wrong.

Comment: Also, the `strtok` function *modifies* the string passed to it, by replacing the first token it find with a string terminator. So the only way to make `temp` be the whole string is to make it an array and copy the string to it.

Comment: Finally, unless the allocation of `str->str` fails, the pointer will *never* be `NULL`.

Comment: Yes, If I put random spaces and tabs after "Hello", 'strtok' doesn't work correctly and never reaches the second word. If increment str->str, it works perfectly. Am I not doing it correctly?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you want to do... Do you want to split the input string into two parts, the first word and the rest of the input, and then skip all leading white-space? You *can* do that when reading the input using `scanf`, but if you want to do it using `strtok` you code seems overly complicated.

Comment: How would I take two inputs with `scanf`? And yes, I do want to split it into two parts skipping all the leading white space. So token 1 will be `Hello` and token 2 will be `Earth lings etc...`.

Comment: Using `scanf`, [something like this](http://ideone.com/ByNeqb).

Comment: Thanks for all the help! This is what I was looking for.

Comment: don't do anything like: `str->str++;` because that is overwriting a pointer that was set via a call to malloc().  Such overwriting looses the original pointer, so the allocated memory cannot be passed to `free()`  This results in a memory leak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this statement before the last if block in the split function

`str->str = strtok(str->str," \t");`    like

```
str->str = strtok(str->str," \t");
if(str->str != NULL)
{
    puts("In null if");
    str->two = strtok(str->str, "");
}
```

you split the string based on the `"\t"` as the delimiter but you never changed the `str->str` string, use the above snippet and it should work fine

Answer (score 2):

`strtok` is a funny function that both modifies the string you pass it, and stores information about it internally. You should pass your string to `strtok` once, then pass in NULL on subsequent calls. For instance, if your goal is to simply break a string up into tokens (which is obviously what `strtok` is for), then something like:

```
#define BUFFER_SIZE 256
int main(void) {
    char *buffer = malloc(BUFFER_SIZE);
    if (!buffer) {
        return -1;
    }

    fgets(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, stdin);

    char *word;
    char *ptr = buffer;
    printf("Tokens: [");
    while ((word = strtok(ptr, " \t\n"))) {
        printf("%s, ", word);
        ptr = NULL;
    }
    printf("]\n");

    free(buffer);
}
```

will work. When I run the code like this:

```
./quick
when in the fun   apple         orange
```

I get the following result:

```
Tokens: [when, in, the, fun, apple, orange, ]
```

The important thing is that I only passed the `buffer` pointer to `strtok` on the first time through the loop. After that it is passed NULL.

Comment: Thanks, but I wanted it to save the first word in a char pointer and the rest of the words in another char pointer. I can't figure out how to do that while trying to modify your code.

Comment: Ah, then `strtok()` is probably not your best solution - it is really intended to break a string into a series of tokens. If you know the format of the string in advance, and only want to pull off a single piece of it, use `scanf` as Joachim suggested previously